# Error on file saving

Tags: php, file

When I create file on Windows hosting, it gets name like `РґР¶СѓР»РёСЏ.jpg`

It has to be a cyrillic name.

`fopen()` is used for creation.

**What can I do with this?**

Comment: We're going to need some more info about how you're creating the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an encoding issue.
Setting PHP to use UTF-8 encoding will probably suffice: http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php

UTF-8 can represent every character in the Unicode character set, plus it has the special property of being backwards-compatible with ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

- Check if all the script files use the same encoding (ANSI, ISO-..., UTF-8, etc).
- Check the internal encoding your script use and the encoding of the string

  - [multibyte functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.mbstring.php)
  - [internal encoding of your script](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-internal-encoding.php)
  - [encoding of your string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)
- **NB: Not recommending you to use string input from websites in the filesystem!**

  - But if you expect input in a certain format, be sure to specify the [content type of your html page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).